# Laravel - Collection using map not overriding previous object value

Tags: laravel, collections

I'm trying to overwrite a value in the collection. Basically I have this value with developer in my collection:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assign to new variable

> map returns a new collection instance; it does not modify the
>   collection it is called on. If you want to transform the original
>   collection, use the [transform](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-transform) method.

```
$inquiries = collect([
        (object) [
            "id" => 6,
            "developer" => (object) [
                "id" => 3,
                "name" => "Club Wyndham",
            ],
        ],
    ]);

$collection = $inquiries->map(function ($inquiry) {
   $inquiry->developer = $inquiry->developer->name;
   return $inquiry;
});

// result as collection
return $collection;

// result as array
return $collection->all();
```

result

```
[
  {
    id: 6,
    developer: "Club Wyndham"
  }
]
```

Comment: Didn't work. Still see it as `"developer":{"id":3,"name":"Wyndham"}`

Comment: Not working, but I edited my question. Maybe with more information it will be helpful.

Comment: @Fly_Moe you can check my answer again